# jquery.load() is not working (not redirect to another page)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, load

I have a webpage about information corporate data. There is a search and add new button. When we click button Add New in Choose Custtype Page, there is a `select option` that contains branch and customer model. Before we click `button save`, we must select the branch and customer model first. After we select, and click `button save`, there will be redirect to Data Form Page. This is my choose `_custtype.php` code :

```
<?php
   session_start();
   require_once('global.php');
   $where_in = '';
   if( isset($_SESSION['moi_status_UserBranch']) && trim($_SESSION['moi_status_UserBranch'])!="" ){
     $xubranch = explode(",",$_SESSION['moi_status_UserBranch']);
     if( count($xubranch)>0 ){
       $mxt = array();
       foreach($xubranch as $r){
         $mxt[] = "'".$r."'";
       }
       $where_in = implode(",",$mxt);
     }
   }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Order</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jqueryui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/css/mytheme.css" type="text/css"/>

      <script src="template/js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript></script>
      <script src="lib/jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="template/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script src="template/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script src="template/js/jquery.imask.js" type="text/javascript ></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <b>Choose Branch and Customer Model</b>
   <br /><br />
   <form id="search" class="formular" method="post" action="choose_custtype.php" style="z-index:1;">
   <table width="100%">
       <tr>
          <td width="110">Branch</td>
          <td>
              <select id="ownergroupid" name="ownergroupid" class="readonly validate[required]"><option value="">-- CHOOSE --</option>
                 <?php $code = $db->GetOne("SELECT OWNERGROUPID FROM FNTLOANAPPLICATION WHERE DATAID = '".$_GET['id']."'");
                       $branch = $db->GetAll("SELECT CAB_ID, CABANG_NAME FROM COMPANY_PROFILE WHERE CAB_ID IN (".$where_in.") ORDER BY CABANG_NAME ASC");
                       foreach($branch as $k => $v) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $v[0];?>" <?php echo $v[0]==$code?"selected":"";?>><?php echo $v[1];?></option>
                 <?php  } ?>
              </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td width="110">Customer Model</td>
          <td>
              <select id="customer_model" name="customer_model" class="readonly validate[required]">
                 <option value="">Choose</option>
                 <option value="I">Personal</option>
                 <option value="C">Corporate</option>
             </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <input type="submit" id="btnsubmits" name="btnsubmit" class="button" value="Save" />
   <?php //echo "aaaa"; ?>
   </form>
   <script>
      $('#btnsubmits').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#ownergroupid').val() == ''){
           alert('Branch must fill!');
        }else if ($('#customer_model').val() == ''){
           alert('Customer Model must fill!');
        }else
        search.submit();
     });
    </script>

    <?php if (@$_POST['customer_model']): ?>
    <?php 
       $_SESSION['customer_model_new'] = ($_POST['customer_model']); 
       $_SESSION['ownergroupid_new'] = ($_POST['ownergroupid']); 

       //echo "aaaa";
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.opener.location.href = "index.php";
       //window.opener.document.location.href = "index.php";
       window.close();
    </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

this is my `index.php` :

```
<?php
   session_start();
   require_once('global.php');

   //echo "test";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Pooling Order</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jqueryui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/css/mytheme.css" type="text/css"/>

      <?php //echo "test2"; ?>
      <script src="template/js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="lib/jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="template/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script src="template/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <?php //echo "test3"; ?>
      <script src="template/js/jquery.imask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <?php //echo "test4"; ?>
      <script>
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#formlist').load('data_form.php?dataid=<?php echo $_GET['dataid']; ?>&customer_model=<?php echo $_GET['customer_model']; ?>&ownergroupid=<?php echo $_GET['ownergroupid']; ?>');
         });
      </script>

      <?php //echo "test5"; ?>
   </head>

   <body>
      <table width="100%" height="">
         <tr>
            <td align="right">
               <!--<input type="button" id="list" name="list" class="button" value=" List " />-->
               <!-- <input type="button" id="form" name="form" class="button" value=" Form " />-->
               <div id="form"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <div id="formlist"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

As we see from the code, after we select branch and customer model, the page will be redirect into `index.php`, and then `data_form.php. data_form.php` is a form to input data. But, `data_form.php` can not load. Is it because of the jquery / javascript from `index.php` ? i suspect on it :

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $('#formlist').load('data_form.php?dataid=<?php echo $_GET['dataid']; ?>&customer_model=<?php echo $_GET['customer_model']; ?>&ownergroupid=<?php echo $_GET['ownergroupid']; ?>');
   });
</script>
```

previously i use `php 5.2` and its work, but not in `php 5.5`(i upgrade php 5.2 into 5.5). Is this because of different syntax ? (not compatible in php 5.5)

Comment: Do you have some errors?if yes please post it.I notice $_GET['dataid'] might not be set.

Comment: put double quotes ["dataid"] instead of single.IT will throw you an error.

Comment: there is no error. it is only can not reidrect to another page

Comment: I can't figure out how your code works, regarding two points. 1) `window.opener.location.href = "index.php";` seems to redirect as soon as the `choose_custtype.php` page is loaded. 2) `$('#formlist').load(...);` is supposed to always have a callback function argument, while here it gets only the (optional) `data` argument. Could you enlight us about these points? In the other hand, maybe it's a copy/paste issue but `choose_custtype.php` lacks ending quote of the `type="text/javascript"` attribute in the very last `<script>` tag in `<head>`, so the entire code behaviour becomes unpredictable.

Comment: @Shubham i use double quotes but nothing has changed :(

Comment: @cFreed yes.. after we select and click button save in choose_custtype.php, then redirect to index.php, then redirect to load data_form.php. data_form.php is a form about what we select in choose_custtype.php. But, in php 5.2, its works fine, the form can appear. But not in php 5.5. is this because of different snytax between php 5.2 and 5.5 ? still no idea to fix this issue :(

Comment: Sorry but I can't at all understand how this code could work like you tell, since it has notably two points with no sense (see my previous post). Matbe I could say more if you explain them.